# Order model by its association quantity's

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to order some Product in my index view by there stock's quantity (if there is 0 it comes last and if above 0, it comes first).

I have models:  Product, Variant, and Stock

Product model

```
has_many :stocks,   through: :variants
```

Variant Model

```
belongs_to :product
```

Stock model

```
belongs_to :variant
```

This is how I find the whole stock of one product...

```
 p = Product.last
 p.stocks.map(&:quantity).sum
```

Now, how can I find all products stocks quantity and from the biggest to the smallest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for all `Product` to be returned in descending order based on the Sum of the `Stock` quantity. If so this should work for you.

```
@products = Product.left_joins(variants: :stocks) 
       .group(:id)
       .select(Product.arel_table[Arel.star],
               Stock.arel_table[:quantity].sum.as('total_quantity'))
       .order('total_quantity DESC')
```

This will result in

```
SELECT 
  products.*,
  SUM(stocks.quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM 
  products 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON variants.product_id = products.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN stocks ON stocks.variant_id = variants.id
GROUP BY 
  products.id
ORDER BY 
  total_quantity DESC
```

Which appears to be what you want. This will also add a virtual attribute `total_quantity` to all the loaded `Product` objects which you can use for display purposes without hitting the database again e.g.

```
@products.each do |p|
  p.total_quantity # virtual attribute equal to SUM(stocks.quantity)
end
```

**As a final aside;** if you actually use `p.stocks.map(&:quantity).sum` in your code you can change this to `p.stocks.sum(:quantity)` for efficiency reasons. This will execute a `SELECT SUM()` query appropriate to the `ActiveRecord::Relation` returned by `p.stocks` which in general will be much better than loading all the `Stock` objects, then generating an `Array` of the quantities, and then iteratively accumulating said quantities into a numeric value.

Comment: Many thanks for your help
I have a mistake `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "stocks.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... t0_r17, "products"."discounted_price" AS t0_r18, "stocks"."...`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this in the view and don't care whether you end up with an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or an `Array`, you could use the [Enumerable#sort_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) method.

Eg in a haml view:

```
- @products.sort_by { |p| p.stocks.sum(:quantity) }.reverse.each do |product|
  Qty: #{product.stocks.sum(:quantity)}
```

If you were to define a method on `Product` that calculates its quantity, like this:

```
def stock_quantity
  stocks.sum(:quantity)
end
```

You could clean it up a bit:

```
- @products.sort_by(&:stock_quantity).reverse.each do |product|
  Qty: #{product.stock_quantity}
```

Comment: This will execute N*2 + 1 queries (probably less than desirable). `sum` is a query method and you are calling it twice for each `Product` in `@products`

Comment: Yes. I didn't do so in my example, but it could be memoized in the `stock_quantity` method.